# Delete Old Folders in Jenkins after X days

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /home/jenkins/workspace/awesome-integration-into-jenkins/mochawesome-report to 
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/IDE/jobs/ide-application/branches/subtask-I.anjt14c4kifi.o-jenkins/builds/5/htmlreports/Mochawesome_20Report
```

This output is obtained after running:

```
post {
    always {
        sh 'rm mochawesome-report/mochawesome.json'

        publishHTML (target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: "$WORKSPACE/mochawesome-report/",
            reportFiles: 'mochawesome.html',
            reportName: "Mochawesome Report"
        ])

        cleanWs()
    }
}
```

I am using *htmlpublisher* to publish test report after all steps in the pipeline are complete. As can be seen from the output, the files are copied to *var/jenkins_home/jobs/IDE/jobs/mosaiq-ide-application/branches/subtask-I.anjt14c4kifi.o-jenkins/builds/**BUILDNUMBER**/*. There is no setting in htmlpublisher that allows the user to delete old report folders. Is there a plugin that I can use in the post pipeline step that looks inside the *..../builds/**BuildNumber**/htmlreports* folder and checks if it is x days old, and removes it. Or how can I efficiently achieve the desired result?

Comment: All the old artifacts are deleted with the build that created them. You can configure max number of builds or max days to keep them. The idea is that you either need *both* the build and its artifacts, or you need none of them. There is no option to erase specific files, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MaratC The htmlpublisher plugin copies the given html folder to a separate location, such that when cleanWs() is performed, those html files are not deleted. Is it possible to set an expiration time for those files. How do I make the max number of builds or max configuration work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44155346/2047614.