# Build retention policy of the artifactory jenkins plugin does not delete all files of Conan packages

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, conan

We use the Artifactory Jenkins plugin in combination with Conan. In our jenkinsfile we use the following line to delete old builds and artifacts:

```
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 3, deleteBuildArtifacts: true, async: true
```

However, this does not delete the entire package. The following folders and files remain in the Artifactory:

[image: Artifactory Conan Package after retention]

Used versions:
Artifactory Jenkins Plugin: 3.6.1

Does anyone have similar problems or sees a bug in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542485/how-to-write-pipeline-to-discard-old-builds