# How to delete original jenkins build after archiving the build

Tags: java, jenkins

I am using below Jenkinsfile to create maven build and archive it after.

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            withMaven(maven: 'mvn installed') {
                sh "mvn clean package"
            }
        }
        post {
            success {
                archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After archiving the build it gets saved to target folder which has the jar file I want to use. However the build folder also contains the original com.. folder that contains the same jar. Is there any way I can delete this com folder after archiving, because it is just taking extra space in my server that I am not using at all.

Edit: I am not looking to clean the workspace but rather the original com folder inside the builds/<build_no>/archive/ folder

Answer (score 1):

Based on @dev-joshi's edit,

> not looking to clean the workspace but rather the original com folder
> inside the builds/<build_no>/archive/ folder

I am guessing you are referring to the the target location for the **"Archive the artifacts"** post-build step and not the ./target directory, output of the maven compile step.

Your answer lies  in the **"[ X ] Discard old builds"** option
[image: Discard Old Builds option]

**"Max # of builds to keep with artifacts"** `[ 1 ]` 
*[if not empty, only up to this number of builds have their artifacts retained]*
Setting that to `[ 1 ]` should achieve your objective.

If using a pipeline, [this S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542485/598141) and the [syntax docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options) provides the syntax options:

```
 options { 
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactNumToKeepStr: '1')) 
 }
```

You will have to execute another build for the existing artifacts to be cleaned up.

I'd also suggest you set Archive option:
"**`[ X ]` Archive artifacts only if build is successful**"
You don't want to blow away successful artifacts with a partially completed build.

**Note too**: [`mvn install`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/index.html) will copy the generated artifacts to the local repo, following standard maven rules. That is normally outside the local workspace (unless choosing [ x ] private repo). You can then run [`mvn clean`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/) to delete the intermediary artifacts (`*.class` and `*.jar`, etc.) from the local workspace, returning you back to pre-build state. You can use the **"Delete workspace"** post-build step with "Patterns for files to be deleted" to achieve a similar effect (if you know what you are doing, or to simply remove the workspace entirely.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Workspace Cleanup plugin and add to the post section

```
post {
  success {
    archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
    cleanWs ()
  }
  failure {
    cleanWs ()
  }
}
```

You can add `cleanWs` to `always` block, but in this case `always` is executing first all the time.