# Limit the number of builds stored in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, limit

A "log rotation" strategy should be implemented in the Jenkins pipeline to only store the last 5 builds

This change should be made in the pipeline script itself (not through the Jenkins UI) to ensure the configuration is checked in.

Comment: Have you checked [Override the settings with a job specific discarder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-discarder/#plugin-content-override-the-settings-with-a-job-specific-discarder)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Pipeline to discard old builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542485/how-to-write-pipeline-to-discard-old-builds)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in).

You can configure build retention **before** the publish build info step:

- [declarative pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention):

```java
stage ('Set build retention') {
    steps {
        rtBuildInfo (
            maxBuilds: 5
        )
    }
}
```

You can find a good example [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile).

- [scripted pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention):

```java
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 5
```

You can find a good example [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/vars-build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile).

Comment: Thanks but will this syntax remove old build from artifactory as well?

Comment: @Vishal yes, it should remove also old builds with the same build name

Comment: ,i tried to add the code but seems to not deleting old builds from artifactory, below is the code snippet

stage("Artifactory Upload") {
  def directory = "generic-local/XYZ/ABC/${params['version']}/${currDate}/${buildNo}/"
  def server = Artifactory.server 'art-int'
  def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10,deleteBuildArtifacts: true
  
  

  def upload_spec_bin = """{
   "files": [
    {
     "pattern": "*",
     "target": "${directory}",
     "exclusions": ["*.txt"]
    }
   ]
  }"""

  server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin
 }

Comment: if you have any update please let me know .

Comment: Looks like you forgot to publish the build info: server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo

Comment: that also not working

Comment: stage("Artifactory Upload") {
  def directory = "generic-local/ABC/XYZ/${params['version']}/${currDate}/${buildNo}/"
  def server = Artifactory.server 'art-int'
  def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
  server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
  
  

  def upload_spec_bin = """{
   "files": [
    {
     "pattern": "*",
     "target": "${directory}",
     "exclusions": ["*.txt"]
    }
   ]
  }"""
  
  server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin
 }

@yahavi

Comment: i am not sure what i am missing here
=================
    stage("Artifactory Upload") {
  def directory = "generic-local/ABC/XYZ/${params['version']}/${currDate}/${buildNo}/"
  def server = Artifactory.server 'art-int'
  def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
  server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
  
  

  def upload_spec_bin = """{
   "files": [
    {
     "pattern": "*",
     "target": "${directory}",
     "exclusions": ["*.txt"]
    }
   ]
  }"""
  
  server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin
 }

Comment: @Vishal you should publish the build info after the upload and change the maxBuilds to 5

Comment: yes i did that as well pls see below snip

stage("Artifactory: Upload") {
def server = Artifactory.server 'art-int'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
def upload_spec_bin = """{
"files": [
{
"pattern": "${syncapp_binary_name}",
"target": "generic-local/XYZ/ABC/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/"
}
]
}"""
server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 5, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}

Comment: `stage("Artifactory Upload") {
  def directory = "generic-local/ABC/XYZ/${params['version']}/${currDate}/${buildNo}/"
  def server = Artifactory.server 'art-int'
  def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
  
  
  

  def upload_spec_bin = """{
   "files": [
    {
     "pattern": "*",
     "target": "${directory}",
     "exclusions": ["*.txt"]
    }
   ]
  }"""
  
  server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin
  server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
 }

`

Comment: @VSK looks like you published an empty build info. Please attach the buildinfo object to the upload command to make sure the uploaded artifact will be attached to the build: `server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin, buildInfo: buildInfo`

Comment: does the build retention feature work for artifactory OSS version , or it work only on artifactory pro?,

Comment: [link] https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in
as in this it says artifactory pro is required